# Fast access to data without using a database?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm looking for a solution to access some buffered data in a fast way:

I have a bunch of (let's say up to 200) cached position information consisting of latitude and longitude plus some additional information. Now I want to (very frequently) compare my current position and find that position out of this cache-list, that is closest to current one. Doing a distance calculation for all the cached positions to find the nearest one is a resource-eating thing and something I would prefer to avoid.

Additionally there needs to be the possibility to add new positions to the cached list and to remove old ones - but this is an easy thing since it is not time-critical and done only rarely.

So any ideas? How could I evaluate the closest position out of my list of cached positions as efficient as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you use a database for this? SQLite would be able to do this really fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you should be using SQLite for this, especially if performance is important to you. It doesn't have to be complicated, all you need is a simple table with your markers

```
CREATE TABLE markers(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lat REAL, lon REAL);
```

Fill in your table first

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO markers VALUES (NULL,lat1,lon2);
....
INSERT INTO markers VALUES (NULL,lat200,lon200);
COMMIT;
```

And then a simple query will do the job to find the closest marker to the position (x,y)

```
SELECT * FROM markers ORDER BY (x-lat)*(x-lat)+(y-lon)*(y-lon) LIMIT 1;
```

You don't need a square root in the `ORDER BY` because sqrt is a monotonous function.

Comment: That "SELECT ... LIMIT 1" thingy looks lean and small but in my opinion it isn't! What does the database do internally? I guess it has to do the same in a general way like I can do with specialised code way more faster: calculate the difference to _each_ stored location just to find the one, closest one.

Comment: Elmi, you are wrong, databases are meant for large computations and are designed to handle such queries, whatever code you write, will be slower than what the SQl will take to compute that statement.

Comment: @LuckyMe is exactly write, I can guarantee you will NOT be able to code anything faster than this query and I doubt many people could. Why don't you try and code it to see how much time this query takes? You will be pleasantly surprised ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `SQLite` DB the only way I see you can do that is to save your locations to a file (`text file/xml file`) and on an access to your application parse this file to a structure in memory like a `List/ArrayList`.

You will have to check if this structure is null on every access to your application and parse it again if it is null.

Comment: Where is the advantage of such a solution? For finding the closest position the same calculations would be done plus some additional resources for parsing of SQL statements, accessing the interfaces, data retrieval from disk.

Comment: advantage as compare to what? you said you didn't want to use SQLite DB this would be the best option after it. You right about the parsing time and disk access that will take time. But in the end you will have to store the data in some sort of fashion. You can't just leave it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a file and accessing it is the same as the SQL, the difference is so minute that it is irrelevant, because they are both accessing the "hard-disk" (in Mobile, the storage space) and therefore same delay.

I like the SQLite database idea, because you can check the entire table with one statement to get the right answer (you just have to structure the statement right). Keep in mind that SQL is an extremely smart and efficient type of database storage, the data that get cached from the "disk" (table) stays cached until the space is needed.

HOWEVER, if you wish, you could read the table once, put it in memory (some globally accessible variable), then carry on from there.

PS: I would say re-consider the SQLite DB and do some test timings for your app and see the results.
Let me know what happens, I am interested.

Comment: I think what Elmi meant with cache was an in-memory cache, where access times are way lower than those to touch the disk.

Comment: Opps, must have missed that part, Emil is correct, unless you want to use Shared Preferences (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Elmi, your terminology is inaccurate, any data storage is considered database, so are you referring to SQL by "access data without using database"?

Comment: @LuckyMe, the OP wanted a way to use his locations data without the use of DB (I see this as the build in SQLite DB option). So the next best option would be to use a file for that. The OP can't leave the locations data in memory because this data may be deleted by GC if the user leaves the app for a certain time. I don't know a way of saving 200 entries (what the OP needs) in to SharedPreferences.

Comment: @Emil Adz, What is OP and GC? it is possible to systematically save into SharedPreferences. But again, I am with you, I would order them: SQL > File > SharedPreferences. With recommendation of SQL for sure.

Comment: OP - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean
GC - Garbage Collector.
I would be glad if you could present me a way to save 200 entries in SharedPreferences. And I agree with you on the order but the OP asked specifically for a solution without the DB so this is the next best option.

Comment: @all: OK, with "DB" I meant a thing where I query some tables using something like SQL and that does data retrieval internally according to my query ;-)

Comment: Ex. `editor.putDouble("location x" + i + " long" + i, longi);` put it in a for-loop and put the lati with it in a 200 looping, and you got the database :D Iffy way of doing it, but technically it is doable. I am sure you know that all of these are types of databases, the OP screwed up the terminology, it is best not to endorse the screw up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a database, consider storing your data in-memory using some form of [Binary Space Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) tree. If you're just interested in 2D space, then a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) will work. This can significantly reduce the complexity of your search, versus a simple linear search, and copes well with sparsely populated areas (e.g. if a lot of points are clustered in particular areas, quite far apart from each other).

There are other BSP trees that may be more efficient, but are typically harder to implement and debug. You may want to find a library to save yourself having to write the data structure from scratch.